# How to make the task fail when the calling stored procedure throws an error

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I had a stored procedure to insert the data from a stage which is called by task. if the load fails(due to on_error= skip_file option) it throws an error which is handled. but the status of the task shows as success. what to do to make the task fail when there is error in stored procedure.
here is the sample code

```
create or replace procedure sample_procedure()
returns varchar not null
language javascript
execute as caller    
as
$$
    try
    {
       try
        {
            var ct_table_cmd = `create or replace table sample_table_temp like sample_table`;
            var ct_table_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: ct_table_cmd});
            var result_set= ct_table_stmt.execute();
             result_set.next();
        }
        catch(err)
        {
           var queryId = ct_table_stmt.getQueryId();
           var queryText = ct_table_stmt.getSqlText();
           var log_insert_into=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:`insert into error_table
               (code, message, queryid, querytext) VALUES (?,?,?,?);`
               ,binds : [err.code, err.message,queryId,queryText]
            });
            log_insert_into.execute();
            var ct_task_ret_value = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call system$set_return_value('{err.message'});`}).execute();
            return err.message;
       }
        var copy_cmd = `copy into smaple_table_temp from @mystage
                 file_format=(format_name= 'sample_csv_format')
                 files=('/file_name')
                 on_error=skip_file;`;
 

         var copy_cmd_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:copy_cmd});
        var result_set =copy_cmd_stmt.execute();
        result_set.next();
       if(result_set.getColumnValue(2)=='LOADED')
       {
          var swap_cmd = `alter table sample_table_temp swap with sample_table;`;
          var swap_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: swap_cmd});
          swap_stmt.execute();
       }
       else if (result_set.getColumnValue(2)== 'LOAD_FAILED')
      {
        var err_message= result_set.getColumnValue(7);
        var queryId = copy_cmd_stmt.getQueryId();
        var queryText = copy_cmd_stmt.getSqlText();
        var log_insert_into=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:`insert into error_table
         (code, message, queryid, querytext) VALUES (?,?,?,?);`
         ,binds : [err.code, err.message,queryId,queryText]
          });
        var task_ret_value = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call system$set_return_value('{err_message'});`}).execute();
        log_insert_into.execute();
        return err_message
  
     }
    }
$$
;
```

The error log table and task to call the procedure is :

```
create or replace table error_table (ts timestamp_ntz, src varchar(50),code varhcar(100) , 
                                   message varchar, queryid varchar, querytext varhcar);
```

create or replace task sample task
warehouse = 'my_warehouse'
schedule= '10 minute'
as
call sample_procedure();

when the task call the procedure with no data in the location it throws an error in the task history  as "execution error in stored procedure sample procedure:

> SQL compilation error:
> Syntax error line at position 47 unexpected 'remote'. at statement.execute, line 172 position 111". but the actual error is "remote file is not existed at. there are several potential causes. The file might not exist. The required credentials may be missing or invalid."

and when the table is not existed, the error shown is different in task_history of information schema. It is not showing the error which is shown when the procedure is called independently (i.e call sample_procdure()).

Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the return value for the task here:

```
var ct_task_ret_value = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call system$set_return_value('{err.message'});`}).execute();
```

You're setting the return for the stored procedure here:

```
return err.message;
```

The problem is `err.message` is a string containing the text of an error message, which is not an error indication. You've caught the error, so as far as Snowflake's concerned it's been handled.

To indicate an error on SP execution, you can either 1) not catch the error or 2) catch the error, handle it, and throw an error.

Option 2 seems to be what you're looking to do. Catch the error as you're already doing, but instead of returning `err.message`, do this:

```
//return err.message;
throw err.message;
```

Snowflake will wrap the error message with its own error text. There is currently no way to avoid that, so you may want to do something in the text to call out attention to your error text like *wrapping in stars* or something like that. [Snowflake Stored Procedure Exception & Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175998/snowflake-stored-procedure-exception-failure)

Comment: name: @Greg when used throw err.message , it's showing as uncaught the error but logging the error into log table , but when used the return err.message it's giving the actual error. how to handle this?