# snowflake stored giving different error when used throw error instead of return error

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored procedure where it loads the data from the external stage and is being called using a task. I want to make the task to fail when the stored procedure gives an error. as said in the answer [How to make the task fail when the calling stored procedure throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091759/how-to-make-the-task-fail-when-the-calling-stored-procedure-throws-an-error) i used `throw err.message` instead of `return err.message`.here is the sample code.

```
returns varchar not null
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
try
{
      try
        {
         var create_table=snowflake.cresteStatement({sqlText:`create or replace table tableB like 
                                               tableA`});
          create_table.execute();
        }
     catch(err)
        {
          var query_id = create_table.getQueryId();
          var query_txt = create_table.getSqlText();
          var log_insert = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:`insert into error_table
               (code, message, queryid, querytext) VALUES (?,?,?,?);`
               ,binds : [err.code, err.message,queryId,queryText]});
              log_insert.execute();
         throw err.message
        }
      var copy_cmd = `copy into tableb from @myext_stg/<folder>
                      file_format=(format_name='my_csv_format')
                      files=('/file_name')
                      on_error=skip_file;`;
      var copy_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: copy_cmd})
      var copy_stmt_result = copy_stmt.execute();
          copy_stmt_result.next()
      if(copy_stmt_result.getColumnValue(2)=='LOADED')
        {
          var swap_cmd = `alter table tableB swap with tableA;`;
          var swap_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: swap_cmd});
          swap_stmt.execute();
        }
     else if(copy_stmt_result.getColumnValue(2)=='LOAD_FAILED')
       {
         var err_message= result_set.getColumnValue(7);
        var queryId = copy_cmd_stmt.getQueryId();
        var queryText = copy_cmd_stmt.getSqlText();
        var log_insert_into=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:`insert into error_table
         (code, message, queryid, querytext) VALUES (?,?,?,?);`
         ,binds : [err.code, err_message,queryId,queryText]
          });
         throw `${err_message}`
       }
 }
catch(err)
{
  throw `final error: ${err.message}`
}
$$;
```

but i got the following errors:"JavaScript execution error: Uncaught  undefined in MYPROCEDURE at ' throw `final error: ${err.message}`' position 1 stackstrace: MYPROCEDURE line: 26." but the actual error is, there is source table with name tableA in the schema.
another error is shown as uncaught error: unsupported type of binding arguments. but the actual error is no file existed at the location.
as answered in the question [Snowflake Stored Procedure Exception & Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175998/snowflake-stored-procedure-exception-failure) how to prevent the throw from generating new error as in my case same is happening.
any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message indicates, the variable `err` is undefined here:

```
[err.code, err_message,queryId,queryText]
```

That variable doesn't get defined until the catch block here:

```
catch(err)
{
  throw `final error: ${err.message}`
}
```

In the line that's causing the error, you have it in the `else` block of an `if` statement. That is not a JavaScript error condition. It's only detecting a failure on load that's reported as a normal variable state to JavaScript.

Instead of `err` here, you should be inserting other available information about why the load failed:

```
var log_insert_into=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:`insert into error_table
         (code, message, queryid, querytext) VALUES (?,?,?,?);`
         ,binds : [err.code, err_message,queryId,queryText]
          });
```